# Network connectiviy alert view in iPad app

Tags: iphone, objective-c

How to show the alert view if there is no network because i am getting data from xml which is on server.

Comment: look into Reachability classes from apple

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the Apple Reachability.

Check out this

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html

Answer (score 1):

As everybody said, you need to use Reachability.h and Reachability.m.
But nobody said about correct variant with notifications:

First you need to add variable to your class. It will be better declare it private in `.m` file:

```
@implementation YourClass
Reachability* reachability;

@end
```

Then you must create new Reachability and add observer (self) to Notification Center:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                                 selector:@selector(showInetConnection)
                                                     name:kReachabilityChangedNotification
                                                   object:nil];
        reachability = [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] retain];
        [reachability startNotifier];
```

…

```
-(void)showInetConnection
{
    if ([reachability currentReachabilityStatus]==NotReachable) {
        UIAlertView* view = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                                       message:@"There are no inet connection"
                                                      delegate:nil
                                             cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" 
                                             otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [view show];
        [view release];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add "Reachability.h" into your UIViewController subclass and use this code where applicable.

```
  if (![[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection] isReachable]) {
    [[[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet connection!"
                                 message:@"You have no active internet connection. Please enable wi-fi and re-launch the app."
                                delegate:nil
                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                       otherButtonTitles:nil, nil] autorelease] show];
    return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with checking network availability.
Apple's Reachability code will throw errors under iOS5 ARC feature.

Finally i found this working project in gitHub
https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability

Its very easy to implement and instructions are give in the site itself.

BR,
Hari